# Cplex Java API: Very large numbers (> 64bit) or exact floating point numbers

Tags: java, cplex

In my minimization problem, I need to minimize a term whose factors can be very large (e.g. 2^200 for some instances). E.g., I need to add objective terms like

```
objective.addTerm(vars.get(i).get(j), math.pow(2,200); // vars is a list of lists of IloNumVar, objective is of type IloLinearNumExpr
// ... Add terms for all cvars ...
cplex.addMinimize(objective);
```

Is there a way to add such large objective terms to cplex? I am running cplex 12.3 and the API only offers me to pass variables of type double. It seems like there is no support for BigIntegers?

Another solution would be to scale down all values to a range [0,2^32]. However the results are not optimal, due to rounding errors. Is cplex supporting BigDecimals or some equivalent types?

Comment: I think that you just need to scale it. If you have a problem of significant size (numbers of vars and constraints) then you will usually only prove optimality to within a certain tolerance. The rounding errors on your large numbers will probably not be significant compared to the optimality tolerance. The default optimality tolerance is something like 1e-5 and I have gone tighter on some problems; but usually we tend to relax that and accept a larger tolerance in order to get reasonable run times.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically, no, there is no support for BigInteger's.  You can verify this by looking through the [CPLEX Java Reference Manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/overview-summary.html).

As has been mentioned in the comments, you'll likely want to scale those large coefficients.  For variable upper bounds, it's worth keeping in mind that CPX_INFBOUND (1.0e+20) is treated as infinity (see, for example, the documentation for [CPXXnewcols](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/cpxapi/newcols.html); that is for the C Callable Library, but still pertinent).  Also, make sure that you do not have "a wide variation (say, six or more orders of magnitude) in coefficients found in the objective function" or you can run into [numeric difficulties](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/cont_optim/simplex/20_num_difficulty.html).